# Stepper motor wiring

Tags: stepper-motor, wiring

I have what it looks to me as a stepper motor, power at 24DC, but it has no name or mark, and i can't find any documentation about the wiring, here are some pictures of the plug and the motor.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How are you certain that this is a stepper motor? This device seems to be a educational/training motor made by a company called lucas-nuelle. They have a web site at: https://www.lucas-nuelle.com/ I did find info on the SE 2662 but different variants like the 5D. All were shunt wound DC motors and I suspect yours is also. Google is also your friend ;-)

Comment: It does indeed appear to be a teaching model (that would also explain the low voltage) however a housing like that is probably an induction machine, not a DC motor.  "2662" is more likely a size designator than a functional one.  Given that the company exists you could try contacting them... they might not answer or not usefully given that the product looks to be over 30 years old, but it doesn't hurt to try.  You could also explore the connector with an ohm-meter, spin it up mechanically and examine the leads with a scope, or possibly disassemble and examine internally.

Comment: Why do you assume it's a stepper? Because the shaft protrudes from each end? Not a good indicator. What you need to do is this. Grab the shaft with a large set of pliers and try to rotate it slowly. If it spins smoothly, it is not a stepper. If it is a stepper, it will move in jerks, as it moves from one detent (step position) to another.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally we may come across an old stepper motor salvaged from a printer or an ancient floppy drive. If we are lucky, there will be a part number on the motor and after some digging around, we will come up with a datasheet. Often though, we will have a motor with no markings whatsoever and four, or six colorful wires sticking out. First, we need to figure out how the wires are paired to form coils within the motor. (an example from http://www.powerjackmotion.com/product/2-phrase-110mm-stepper-motor/ )Trial and error may work, but there is a better way! All it takes is a multimeter.

How to identify 2 Phrase stepper motor coil pairs with a multimeter

**Need to consider the following parameters:**

1. Holding Torque Large motors require high torque.
2. Output Speed If the output speed is high, torque is lower and vice versa.
3. Pulses Per Second It refers to no-load starting frequency of stepping motor.
4. Phase 2 Phase motors are often used for normal applications. 3 Phase motors are used for high speed and high torque requirements.
5. Special Parameters, In addition, we may need to consider a few special parameters such as water proofing, output shaft length, and diameter among others.